# How do I insert multiple checkbox values into a table?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, multipleselection

I cant seem to find or figure out a working solution to insert multiple checkbox values from a form into a table. The closes I have come is inserting the value of merely one checkbox value into a table. Kindly point out how I can insert multiple checkbox values and not merely one.

Find below what I have so far:

My form:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="chk123.php">
Flights on: <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="Daily">Daily<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="Sunday">Sunday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="Monday">Monday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="Tuesday">Tuesday <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="Wednesday">Wednesday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="Thursday">Thursday <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="Friday">Friday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="Saturday">Saturday <br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My php file to read and insert the values into a table:

```
<?php

// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

$checkBox = $_POST['Days'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkBox); $i++)
        {
            $query="INSERT INTO example (orange) VALUES ('" . $checkBox[$i] . "')";     

            mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );
        }
    echo "Complete";

}

?>
```

Comment: each call to mysql_query is expensive, consider merging the query to a single insert by chaining the () after values. such as ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ...

Comment: All `mysql_*()` functions are [**officially deprecated**](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp) *(no longer supported/maintained)* and will be [**removed**](http://j.mp/11j2t6j) in the future. You should update your code using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure future functionality. Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should specify

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Daily">Daily<br>
```

as array.

Add `[]` to all names `Days` and work at php with this like an array.

After it, you can `INSERT` values at different columns at db, or use `implode` and save values into one column.

---

Didn't tested it, but you can try like this. Don't forget to replace `mysql` with `mysqli`.

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="chk123.php">
Flights on: <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Daily">Daily<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Sunday">Sunday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Monday">Monday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Tuesday">Tuesday <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Wednesday">Wednesday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Thursday">Thursday <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Friday">Friday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Saturday">Saturday <br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php

// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

$checkBox = implode(',', $_POST['Days']);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{       
    $query="INSERT INTO example (orange) VALUES ('" . $checkBox . "')";     

    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );

    echo "Complete";

}

?>
```

Comment: Wonderful! I checked it and it saves several days in one column. How do I get each day to be saved on each row instead?

Comment: `INSERT INTO example (column1, column2, ...) VALUES ($_POST['Days'][0], $_POST['Days'][1], ...)`

Comment: I am terribly sorry viakondratiuk, I meant on each row and not column

Comment: In that case just change your html and your code should work.

Comment: SirBT, Would you mind sharing the solution of saving the checkbox values in MySql in separate rows? It would help me understand how to write it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare the array in the HTML via

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Daily">
```

Also you can insert multiple items with one query like this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO example (orange) VALUES ";
for ($i=0; $i<count($checkBox); $i++)
    $query .= "('" . $checkBox[$i] . "'),";
$query = rtrim($query,',');
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );
```

---

Also keep in mind that `mysql_*` functions are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) and hence should not be used in new code. You can use PDO or MySQLi instead. See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944958/1557526) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work .. :)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Daily">Daily<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Days[]" value="Sunday">Sunday<br>
```

Comment: kindly be a bit more specific.

Comment: I think you will understand.. :(

Answer (score -3):

I think you should $_POST[][], i tried it and it work :)), tks

Comment: Please provide a full answer with code example to help answer the question. Thanks!