# Checkbox and MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a problem.
I don't know how to put the value of my checkbox in my MySQL database with PHP.
So :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkiard" value="IARD">
```

How to put the value "IARD" in my database ONLY if the checkbox is check ?
Thank you guys.

Comment: after posting form you can access the value of this checkobx using $_POST['checkiard'] and can insert it into database

Comment: You can do this in two ways. One is make an ajax call after check the input and the other is submit the form by check the input, then use $_POST['checkiard'] to get the value of this input.

Comment: Ok, but there is more :
`<input type="checkbox" name="checkiard" value="IARD"> IARD<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkvie" value="vie"> vie
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkplace" value="place"> place`
I've got a lot of checkbox, I want just insert the value **only** if a checkbox is check... And that for all my checkbox !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I insert multiple checkbox values into a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176673/how-do-i-insert-multiple-checkbox-values-into-a-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the value of checkbox as any other input types. Its simply

```
  if(isset($_POST['checkiard'])) {
  $optionArray = implode(",", $_POST["checkiard"]);
  }
```

Try this.

If you have more than one checkbox then you markup should be something like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkiard[]" value="IARD-1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkiard[]" value="IARD-2">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkiard[]" value="IARD-3">
```

you must keep the name same for all the checkbox.

Comment: So I try your solution, but there's a problem : the latest value only is put in the database... If I check IARD-1, IARD-2 and IARD-3, only IARD-3 is put in the database...

Comment: Alright, so you need multiple checkbox to be selected. Then you will have to use array of values. Please check my updated code and let me know.

Comment: It doesn't work... Can I send you a pic of my code and can you tell me where is the problem ?

Comment: How exactly you want to access the values. its better to edit your question and add your php code as well

Comment: look my answer (sorry I'm beginner in this website)

Comment: try the updated code. Also, can you insert your other values in the database?

Comment: OMG IT WORK !!
Thank you so much ! You are a boss ! :D
+1