# multiple values insertion of checkbox only last value is taking in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I need to insert more than one values in checkbox but now it is seemed to be  only the last value am entering is inserting to database.

this is my HTML code

```
<input id="option5" type="checkbox" name="product[]"  value="<?php echo $result["software"];?>"> 

<label for="option5"><span><span></span></span><?php echo $result["software"];?></label>
```

and code for insertion is

```
$array = array($_POST['product']);            
$value = implode(',', $array);        
echo $value;
```

Comment: Will you please provide detail code for this question ?

Comment: Please provide your INSERT query. You are just displaying the POST data.

Comment: take a reference this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176673/how-do-i-insert-multiple-checkbox-values-into-a-table

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save multiple values in database then you need to create multiple checkboxes in html and then save the values with implode() method as below:-

```
<input id="option1" type="checkbox" name="product[]"  value="value1">
<label for="option1">Value1</label>
<input id="option2" type="checkbox" name="product[]"  value="value2">
<label for="option2">Value2</label>
<input id="option3" type="checkbox" name="product[]"  value="value3"> 
<label for="option3">Value3</label>
```

now to store in database you can use implode() method.

```
$values=implode(",",$_POST['product']);
```

now store the $values in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem you are looking for something like this:-

```
$array= array(
'0' => 123,
'1' => 456,
'2' => 789, 
); // this is your post product array oryou want to get last value of that arrray
    -----Or----
$array = $_POST['product']; // your post data after submission

end($array);         // move the internal pointer to the end of the array
$key = key($array);  // fetches the key of the element pointed to by the internal pointer
echo $array[$key]; // 789
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely:

You have multiple checkboxes.

And you want to insert all of them into database.

You need to loop your posted checkboxes.

Your problem is likely that you are not looping over the `$_POST['product']`, so, only, the last product is inserting into database.

So, your checkboxes:

```
<input id="option5" type="checkbox" name="product[]"  value="<?php echo $result["software"];?>">
<label for="option5"><span><span></span></span><?php echo $result["software"];?></label>
```

The code for posted file:

```
if (! empty($_POST['product'])) {
 foreach ($_POST['product'] as $product) {
  // Here, you insert $product into database.
 }
}
```